# Get nodes from a html webpage to crawl URLs using R

Tags: html, r, rvest

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeczg.png

I am trying to get the URLs under the node '.2lines' from the webpage 'https://www.sgcarmart.com/main/index.php'

```
library(rvest)
url <- read_html('https://www.sgcarmart.com/main/index.php') %>% html_nodes('.2lines') %>% html_attr()
```

Which I receive an error for html_nodes function:

```
Error in parse_simple_selector(stream) : 
  Expected selector, got <NUMBER '.2' at 1>
```

How do I get around this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an xpath selector to find the nodes you want. The links are actually contained in `<a>` tags within the `<p>` tags you are trying to reference by class. You can access them in a single xpath:

```r
library(rvest)

site <- 'https://www.sgcarmart.com'

urls <-  site                                           %>%
         paste0("/main/index.php")                      %>%
         read_html()                                    %>% 
         html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@class = '2lines']/a") %>% 
         html_attr("href")                              %>%
         {paste0(site, .)}

urls
#>  [1] "https://www.sgcarmart.com/new_cars/newcars_overview.php?CarCode=12485"
#>  [2] "https://www.sgcarmart.com/new_cars/newcars_overview.php?CarCode=11875"
#>  [3] "https://www.sgcarmart.com/new_cars/newcars_overview.php?CarCode=11531"
#>  [4] "https://www.sgcarmart.com/new_cars/newcars_overview.php?CarCode=11579"
#>  [5] "https://www.sgcarmart.com/new_cars/newcars_overview.php?CarCode=12635"
#>  [6] "https://www.sgcarmart.com/new_cars/newcars_overview.php?CarCode=12507"
#>  [7] "https://www.sgcarmart.com/new_cars/newcars_overview.php?CarCode=12644"
#>  [8] "https://www.sgcarmart.com/new_cars/newcars_overview.php?CarCode=12622"
#>  [9] "https://www.sgcarmart.com/new_cars/newcars_overview.php?CarCode=12650"
#> [10] "https://www.sgcarmart.com/new_cars/newcars_overview.php?CarCode=12651"
#> [11] "https://www.sgcarmart.com/new_cars/newcars_overview.php?CarCode=12589"
#> [12] "https://www.sgcarmart.com/new_cars/newcars_overview.php?CarCode=12649"
```

Comment: hi sir, thanks a lot for your kind assistance. may i ask what does '//*[@class = '2lines']/a'  mean?

Comment: @cepheus this is an example of xpath, which is a better way to look for elements in html or xml. You can read about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp). This particular one looks for all elements where class is "2lines", then finds the `a` elements inside them to return them.